# iPhone: Can I use class method for action selector of UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I want to use class method for selector of action of UIBarButtonItem.

The code is:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithTitle:@"title"                                            
    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
    target: self
    action:@selector(method)]
```

When I use instance method for action, it works.

But when I use class method for action, a error happens when I tap the button.
The error message is: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Can't I use class method for this?
How can I set use for target, instead of self?

Comment: Use [self class] instead of self. You are confusing class methods and instance methods.

Comment: no, navigationbarbutton item is an instant object of navigation bar, and you can only relate instant method to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change to the following code: 
 here the `target` should be `self` instead of `[self class]`

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(method)];
```

Comment: You are welcome, please dont forget to upvote and/or to accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self
    action:@selector(method)];

- (void)method
{
    // here call class method

   [YourClassName methodName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use an instance method. Simply call your class method from your method.